# RoR rendering images inline rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to render an image inline in an email, and my rails app is version 2.3.8.

Can someone provide me with an example of how to do this? Here's what I got so far, but I keep getting errors.

Here's my method:

```
def notice(contact)
subject    'notice'
recipients contact.email
from        'something.com'
sent_on    Time.now
attachments.inline['paypal_seal.gif'] = File.read('/images/paypal_seal.gif')
body       :contact => contact
```

end

And in the view:

```
<%= image_tag attachments['paypal_seal.gif'].url %>
```

This is the error I get:

```
undefined local variable or method `attachments' for #<ContractorNotifier:0x61413c8>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is the 'Rails 3' way of handling attachments. If you are starting out, I highly recommend upgrading to Rails 3. Otherwise, try an older 2.3 guide like:

http://blog.thoughtobject.com/2007/05/26/5/